# Joomla: Edit Article has Title "Submit an Article" in the Front-end

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm having a minor issue: When the user edits any article in the front-end the title of the component is "Submit an Article".

I have worked out how to change it when the user makes a new article (By making the title I want the Page Title in the menu item), but how can I change this title when editing an article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the language file in language folder and choose your language folder after that try to find en-GB.com_content.ini file.

You can search "Submit an Article" and change it whatever you like after "=".

Answer (score 1):

do you know where the language files are?
http://docs.joomla.org/Location_of_template_language_definition_files

so somewhere like [path-to-Joomla]/language/[ln-LN]